# How to point particular domain / subdomain to another domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname, domain-name

I need to point a domain using a CNAME to another domain or subdomain e.g xyz.abc.com point to xyz.com

Means any person open website xyz.com and display (mapping) with xyz.abc.com not redirection of the site.

I have changed cname record but it is not working.

Comment: What is your question (you already answered that one from the title)?

Comment: Probably you need to update `SOA` record also, increasing `serial` field.

Comment: Who can answer this?